# Getting correct output from a string with Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, bash

Guys I want to retrieve a process' affinity list by using subprocess.

```
try:
    pid = 1500
    x = subprocess.check_output(['taskset','-c','-p', str(pid)])
except Exception as inst:
    print inst
```

However, this results in the following output:

```
pid 1500's correct affinity list: 0-3
```

How do I obtain the 0-3 value as a string directly? There can be only integers or a value like 0-3. Basically I'm trying to get what's after colon ':'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python or bash regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split output on `:` and use index 1 to get `0-3`. Later, You can do anything You want with it. Something like this:

```
try:
    pid = 1500
    x = subprocess.check_output(['taskset','-c','-p', str(pid)])
    affinity_list = [affinity for affinity in x.split(':')[1].split('-')]
except Exception as inst:
    print inst
```

This will produce:

```
affinity_list = [0, 3]
```

If You want to interpret `0-3` as a range, You could do this:

```
affinity_list = range(affinity_list[0], affinity_list[-1] + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like `print(str(inst).split(':')[1]`, which gets the string representation of inst, splits it into an array with the delemiter ":" and takes the second value of this array (in your example case, it would be `0-3`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `split()` is perfect for your case, but if you want to use `regex` you could do something like:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "pid 1500's correct affinity list: 0-3"
>>> y = re.search(':.*$',x).group()[1:]
>>> y
' 0-3'
```

But again you don't really need `regex` for this task.